# pulling date from text field

Tags: sql, oracle

not sure if it is possible but this is a text field, called NOTE_TEXT, in the oracle db I'm using. They want to pull the date from it. Is it possible to get 11/6/2018 and 6/13/2018 out of the below results?

NOTE_TEXT results:

- pterris14: On 11/6/2018 at 4:58 PM A Notification letter faxed to
  member.
- blynch16: On 6/13/2018 at 5:25 PM A Notification letter faxed to
  member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(note_text, '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}', 1, 1)
from (select 'pterris14: On 11/6/2018 at 4:58 PM A Notification letter faxed to member.' as note_text from dual) t
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you!